# find gcd$( \lfloor x \rfloor, \lfloor x^a \rfloor)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a way to find gcd$( \lfloor x \rfloor, \lfloor x^a \rfloor)$ assume that $x>1$ and can assume that $a>0$. Also, if close form doesn't exist are there meaningful lower bounds and upper bounds?
Thank you very much.

Comment: The upper bound is $\lfloor x \rfloor$, which is achieved whenever $a,x\in\mathbb{N}$ (assuming $a\ge 1$ actually).

Comment: Thanks. Any ideas about a lower bound

Comment: In general, the lower bound is 1. For example, take $x=\pi, a=3$.  Then $\lfloor x\rfloor=3, \lfloor x^a\rfloor=31$.